# I can't figure out these hotkeys

Tags: mesh, transforms

I think some keybind juggling needs to happen but I don't know where to start. (Also, sorry if it's stupid, I'm new and can't find an answer!)

I updated my application (finally) from 2.8something to 3.0something, which is exciting! Problem is, when I try to move my selection without pressing G, it moves the timeline instead of the selection. I tried switching keybinds around but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know an easy fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "move it without pressing G"? How are you moving it? Are you using the move tool?

Comment: Also where is the mouse cursor when you try to 'move' it?

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear enough, essentially I would not go into the move tool, but just select a vertex in Edit Mode and use the arrow keys to move it in small increments. The mouse cursor is in the 3d viewport when I try to do this.

Comment: Actually it doesn't move with arrows if I select the Move Tool either (from the sidebar icon), only if I press G.